# How can I determine whether I am signed in with a user or service principal in Azure PowerShell and how do I get the ObjectId?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I want to pass on the `ObjectId` of the current user, running a deployment script to a deployment step e.g. to add this current user to Azure Key Vault access policies.

How can I determine this `ObjectId` independent of whether an user or a service principal is executing the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-AzContext` can be used to determine which type of account is used and then `Get-AzADUser` or `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` to get the `ObjectId`:

```
function Get-CurrentAzUserObjectId {
   $objectId = $null
   $ctx = Get-AzContext
   if ($ctx.Account.Type -eq "User") {
       $u = Get-AzADUser -Mail $ctx.Account.Id
       $objectId = $u.Id
   }
   else {
       $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $ctx.Account.Id
       $objectId = $sp.Id
   }
   return $objectId
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I noticed that `Get-AzADUser -Mail $ctx.Account.Id` won't return any records if no mail license is assigned to the user. Can we instead use `Get-AzADUser -UPN $ctx.Account.Id`?